# How to Add Existing Files / Folders to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a folder structure like this in eclipse for my project,

```
Application
-- assets
   -- www
      -- phonegap.js
-- res
   -- xml
      -- phonegap.xml
```

The problem is that the phonegap.js file has been copied onto disk, but is not in the project. Also the xml folder has been copied onto disk but not in the project.

How can I import these into the project? In VS you can just go 'Add -> Existing Item'

I tried to 'Import -> General -> File System' but this seems to add a link to my file / folder as though it is not in the project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To import an external file in the project you can drag the file from the filesystem to the package explorer view of eclipse, then you will be asked to choose if copy the file into the project or just link the file ...

Comment: the other File->Refresh answer is correct for the specific question

Answer (score 32):

I see. It is as simple as selecting 'File -> Refresh' and they are added.

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t259737-eclipse-how-to-add-file-to-project.html

Comment: This is correct answer only for case if files already in the project folder. In huge projects files usually located in different folders. So it is much more efficient to drag them into projects tree, it is strange that there is no option for this action in menu.